# Unserstanging the Wireshark SSL record

Tags: ssl, tcp, wireshark, tls1.2, sslv2

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue where connection is reset.
When i captured the TCP packets in wireshark, I see that Version is shown as SSL2.0 and then after Handshake Message Type, it shows TLS 1.2.
Actually my server only accepts TLS 1.2.
Please help me to understand if client initiated SSL v2.0 or TLS 1.2?

```
SSLv2 Record Layer: Client Hello
  [Version: SSL 2.0 (0x0002)]
  Length: 257
  Handshake Message Type: Client Hello (1)
  Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
  Cipher Spec Length: 216
  Session ID Length: 0
  Challenge Length: 32
  Cipher Specs (72 specs)
  Challenge
```

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We're not general networking/software tech support.

Comment: SSL is a negotiated protocol: the handshake exchanges what the client and the server supports and only then use a numbered version of the protocol (e.g. TLS 1.2).